# Referenced Entity not Updating Correctly When Saved

Tags: 8, entities

I have node A that contains an Entity Reference Revisions field in it set to display as a Rendered Entity that points to node B of a different content type.

Initially this works fine. However, if I make an update to node B and save it, the changes don't appear on node A until I edit and save node A again.

It seems like it should update without having to re-save the parent node. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the reason you use a *Entity Reference Revisions* field? Normally this is more suitable for entities edited inline like paragraphs.

In your case this behavior seems to be what you would expect from this field, because you reference a specific revision of node B and not the latest version you've saved. If you want to do this, then use the core reference field.